# About an example of If Clause

Tags: clauses

"If you are taking something now sleeping"

Can you explain me how this could be correct.

Is this usage for informal native english?

"If you are taking s/t, you will be sleeping." Is this sentence the right way of speaking?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us where you read or heard this? What comes before and after the words you quote?

Comment: I had initially edited *s/t* to make it *something*, but I then realized that would invalidate the existing answer—and I then questioned if you had actually meant it to represent *something* or a different word (which, if so, would normally be represented by *s\*\*t*). Unless you are providing a quotation (in which case a citation should be given), it's best to avoid this kind of shortening of a word (at least without commentary that makes it clear what it stands for).

Comment: Do you mean: taking something to sleep? Like a sleeping pill??

Answer (score 1):

> "If you are taking something now sleeping"

Not correct. You would see this in bad translation for sure, but it could also be a typo of editing ("editing artifact" as I have heard them called i think).

---

> "If you are taking s/t, you will be sleeping."

This is borderline slang, like "you will be tripping," when interpreted literally directly.

But if you interpret is as yet ungrammatical you might recompose as

> "If you **are taking** s/t, you **will sleep.**"
>
> "If **take/took** s/t, you **could sleep/could be sleeping.**"
>
> "If **were taking/had taken** s/t, you **would be sleeping.**"